# barometer sensor in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,i need a modell of a barometer sensor in gazebo.
is there any plugin ,i can use?
how can i modell a barometric sensor? i need this for controlling the hight position of my quadrotor in gazebo.

thanks
regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12553/barometer-sensor-in-gazebo/) by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2012-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find a barometer plugin in the [hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins) package. It currently outputs a [mav_msgs/Height](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/mav_msgs/html/msg/Height.html) message and uses a configurable sensor model to provide (sort of realistic) sensor noise.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0